# Issue while importing Excel ( classic ASP )

Tags: excel, asp-classic

I need to import an Excel file. I am using the following code to connect to the sheet:

```
Set objConn = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Connection")

objConn.Open "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DriverId=790;DBQ=" & Server.mappath(C:\sample\abcd.xls) & ";ReadOnly= false ; UID=admin;"
```

On doing so, I am getting the following error:

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error ''80004005''.
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no
>   default driver specified.

What is causing this error?

Comment: Server.mappath("C:\sample\abcd.xls") Quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the older ODBC drivers, try using the JET drivers (which I've done):

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath(C:\sample\abcd.xls) & ";
Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
```

Or, if your data access drivers are up to date you can use the newer ACE OLEDB drivers (which I've moved to):

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath(C:\sample\abcd.xls) & ";
Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES"";"
```

See [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2003/) for other ways to connect.